# Catch Java Exception in Batch File with errorlevel

Tags: batch-file, exception, errorlevel

I'm trying to catch java exception when processing files in for loop. But although java exception is shown while the loop is running , the errorlevel always equals 0.

Is there another way to catch java exception or maybe my code is wrong?

```
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /s %input%') do (


CALL jhove -m PDF-hul -h xml -o %output%\%%~na.xml %%a

if %ERRORLEVEL% EQU 0 (
 echo errorlevel equals %Errorlevel% )

if %ERRORLEVEL% GEQ 1 (
 echo error )

set /a loop3+=1
)
```

The exception is like this :

```
Verarbeite GBV85882115X
java.lang.ClassCastException: edu.harvard.hul.ois.jhove.module.pdf.PdfSimpleObject cannot be cast to edu.harvard.hul.ois.jhove.module.pdf.PdfDictionary
        at edu.harvard.hul.ois.jhove.module.PdfModule.readDocCatalogDict(PdfModule.java:1344)
        at edu.harvard.hul.ois.jhove.module.PdfModule.parse(PdfModule.java:521)
        at edu.harvard.hul.ois.jhove.JhoveBase.processFile(JhoveBase.java:803)
        at edu.harvard.hul.ois.jhove.JhoveBase.process(JhoveBase.java:588)
        at edu.harvard.hul.ois.jhove.JhoveBase.dispatch(JhoveBase.java:455)
        at Jhove.main(Jhove.java:292)

errorlevel equals 0
```

Comment: Your java program needs to exit with a non zero error like `System.exit(1); `Are you doing that ?

Comment: @svasa  It's can't edit this java program.

Comment: You could wrap the API you are calling around your own caller program and when an exception occurs, you exit your caller program with a non-zero value.

Comment: You need to enable [delayed expansion](http://ss64.com/nt/delayedexpansion.html) by `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion` on top of your script and to write `!ErrorLevel!` instead of `%ErrorLevel%`, since it is modified within the same block of code!

Answer (score 0):

java exceptions are printed in the error stream.May something like this will print it (not tested):

```
set "print="
for /f %%a in ('dir /b /s %input%') do (
  for /f "tokens=* delims=" %%A in ('jhove -m PDF-hul -h xml -o %output%\%%~na.xml %%a 2^>^&1') do (
      echo %%A | find "ClassCastException" >nul 2>&1 && (
         set print=1
      )
      if defined print echo %%A     
 )
)
```